# Select full column in text file (geany)?

Tags: geany

How can I select a full column of text in Geany?

I know that Ctrl + Alt allows me to select a rectangle of text, but if I want to select a full column, I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the file, which is very unproductive.

Comment: For the records: The keybinding is different from Windows to e.g. Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the cursor just before the first entry of the column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. This will enlarge the cursor over the full column. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and the full column will be selected.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + selection with the <kbd>Mouse</kbd> will be more productive for you.

Answer (score 2):

Select a beginning column and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> use <kbd>↓</kbd> key.

Comment: You need to press <kbd>↓</kbd> for every row. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

One of ways to get about this limitation is to simply zoom out in the text editor to make your long file shorter and then use box selection. This way you will be able to select the long columns in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Muzaffar's answer, but maybe a little more efficient if you have a Page Down key:

Select your beginning column, then and press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and use the <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key.

Page Down will go through the rows much more rapidly than ↓.